# Error while developing vsphere plugin

Tags: jersey, vsphere

I am trying to develop vsphere plugin and I'm trying to test using virgo server.
Getting this error when using jersery

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: It looks like the Jersey implementation cannot be found either by the class loader in use or the static initializer of RuntimeDelegateImpl  threw an exception. Is there a full stack trace that you can share?